# Fastest search list of objects by single string

Tags: c#, list, search

I am doing a web application where I have a textbox for searching through a list of objects.

The objects is like :

```
    public class Project : IDbProject
    {
      public string ProjectName { get; set; }
      public string Country { get; set; }
      public string Customer { get; set; }
      public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
      public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

, and the list is a `IList<IProject>`.
My search/filtering is going trough the list, and compares with each string in the object like:

```
        public IList<IProject> GetSearchedProjects(string searchString)
        {

       foreach (var proj in _projects)
                {

                    if (InputStartWithSearch(proj.ProjectName, searchString) && !searchProjects.Contains(proj))
                        {
                            searchProjects.Add(proj);
                            continue;
                        }
                    if (InputStartWithSearch(proj.Country, searchString) && !searchProjects.Contains(proj))
                        {
                            searchProjects.Add(proj);
                            continue;
                        }
                    if (InputStartWithSearch(proj.CreatedBy, searchString) && !searchProjects.Contains(proj))
                        {
                            searchProjects.Add(proj);
                            continue;
                        }
                    if (InputStartWithSearch(proj.ProjectState, searchString) && !searchProjects.Contains(proj))
                        {
                            searchProjects.Add(proj);
                            continue;
                        }
                    if (IsStringDate(searchString))
                        if (IsDatesEqual(proj.CreateDate, searchString) && !searchProjects.Contains(proj))
                        {
                            searchProjects.Add(proj);
                        }
                    }
            return searchProjects;

        }
        return _projects;
    }
```

As you can see, I have made a lot of private methods that will check the search string with the object's string / date / whatever.
And it all works just fine.

But is there a better/faster way to search in a list of objects by a single string?

**EDIT**

The methods `InputStartWithSearch` and `IsStringDate` is private methods, where I check if the input string starts with the project's data. So if the CreatedBy was "Matthi Smith Junior", and I searched for "Matthi Junior", "Matthi Smith", "Smith Junior", etc., it will add it.

The IsStringDate is checking if the search string is a equal to a Datetime format. So it contains an array of formats, and check if the search string is in that format.

Comment: You talk about "faster" - do you actually have performance issues with this at the moment? I'd concentrate on *simple* code first.

Comment: Also, what do InputStartWithSearch and DateToString do? And where does `searchProjects` come from? Why do you have a return statement inside your foreach loop? That looks very wrong to me. I would focus on getting clear and correct code first.

Comment: Not right now, as I am only working with about 30 dummy objects, but when it will be connected to their database, it will be 1000+ objects. So it is working, but if someone could see a way to make it faster, it would be better to change that now, than when it is up and running.

Comment: Why are you doing the search locally if the data is in a database to start with? Try to offload the query to the database. But as I've said, your code is unclear in various ways, and that's what I'd check to start with. Then create a realistic set of test data and performance test that. I'd expect running through (say) 10,000 objects with (say) 10 string checks in each would take hardly any time at all.

Comment: InputStartWithSearch is a private method, that checks the input string with the project field strings. So if the ProjectName is "Project number 100", and I search by "Project 100", it will return true. The same with the other private methods. The 'searchProject' is just a new List, which will contain the searched projects. And then, it has a check to begin with, that if the searchstring is null or empty, it will return the previous lsit of projects.

Comment: I will be connected via a webservice to their database - I will never have a direct access to their database, I have to get it via some JSon parsing, and convert it to Project objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an overloaded method:

```
bool InputStartWithSearch(string search, params string[] inputs)
{
     return inputs.Any(i => InputStartWithSearch(i, string));
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if (InputStartWithSearch(searchString, proj.ProjectName, proj.Country, proj.CreateDate))
{
    searchProjects.Add(proj);
}
```

You can make the list of strings to check as long as you like.

Probably a good idea to reverse the order of the parameters in your original method to make things less confusing too.

To use LINQ directly to get a list of matching projects, you could do:

```
var matchingProjects = _projects.Where(i => InputStartWithSearch(searchString, i.ProjectName, i.Country, i.CreateDate));
```

Comment: Does this makes it any faster, or does it just make it "prettier" and simple? 
I actually like your solution, did not thought about this.

Comment: It won't be fundamentally any faster - it's still doing a serial search to find matches. But readability and code clarity offers real value in itself. As Jon Skeet implied in his comment, this probably won't be the bottleneck in your code - so maintaining clarity most likely outweighs optimization here.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your code slighly and use a Dictionary object where the key is the project name and the value is your object.  Your class would then become:

```
public class Project : IDbProject
{
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public string Customer { get; set; }
  public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
  public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

You would then create a new dictionary object

```
Dictionary <string, Project> myProjects = new Dictionary<string, Project>();
```

Then you'd populate it setting the string to be the project name and when you wanted to reference it you do the following:

```
Project projectDetails = myProjects["projectName"];
```

Obviously change "projectName" to the one you require.

## Edit

Based on the Starts with you could do (code untested)

```
Project projectDetails = myProjects.Where (m => m.Key.Contains ("projectName").Select (m => m.Value);
```

Comment: It looks like the searches are "starts with" ones, which won't work with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could refactor the searchProjects.Contains() check into a guard statement at the top of the loop. That would simplify things. Then you could concatenate the properties of each project into a single string with a unique separator character. Then the search is easier. This isn't any faster than your existing method, it's just shorter.

```
public IList<IProject> GetSearchedProjects(string searchString)
{
    foreach (var proj in _projects)
    {
        if (!searchProjects.Contains(proj))
            continue;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("|").Append(proj.ProjectName);
        sb.Append("|").Append(proj.Country);
        sb.Append("|").Append(proj.CreatedBy);
        sb.Append("|").Append(proj.UploadDate.ToString());

        if (sb.ToString().Contains("|" + searchString))
            searchProjects.Add(proj);
    }
    return searchProjects;
}
```

As long as the '|' character doesn't appear in any of the fields...

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq. Again it's not faster but the code is simpler.

```
public IList<IProject> GetSearchedProjects(string searchString)
{
    return (from p in _projects 
            where searchProjects.Contains(p) &&
                  (InputStartWithSearch(p.ProjectName, searchString) || 
                  InputStartWithSearch(p.Country, searchString) ||
                  InputStartWithSearch(p.CreatedBy, searchString) || 
                  DateToString(p.CreateDate).Contains(searchString.ToLower()))
            select p).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I am not using the standard string.StartWith(). I had to split the strings, and check if substring starts with it. So if ProjectName was "Project number 10", and I searched for "Project 10", "Number 10", or just "Project", it should add that one to the list. So I made my own checking.